# Linked list of characters displaying as numbers

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a linked list of characters, first I'm going to point out that we're not allowed to use the built in methods for linked lists in java already. When I add the characters and then try to display them, it just gives me a list of numbers. Why is this happening?

```
class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        public Node(Character x){
            data = x; next = null;
        }
        public Node next(){return next;}
        public void setNext(Node p){
            next = p;
        }
        public void set(Character x){data = x;}
        public int data(){return data;}
    }



    class Reader{
            Node head = null;//empty list
            public void add(Character x){ //add at head
                Node nw = new Node(x);
                nw.setNext(head);
                head = nw;
            }
            public void display(){
                Node k = head; 
                System.out.print('[');
                while(k!=null){
                    if(k.next!=null)
                        System.out.print(k.data()+","); 
                    else
                        System.out.print(k.data());
                    k=k.next(); 
                }   
                System.out.print(']'); 

            }



        }

    class assignment9{

        public static void main(String[]args){

            Reader r1 =  new Reader();
            r1.add('r');
            r1.add('e');
            r1.add('l'); 
            r1.add('l');
            r1.add('o');
            r1.display();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast to `char`

`System.out.print((char)k.data()+",");`

and

`System.out.print((char)k.data());`

You can use `int` here as you have, but it is best to use the most appropriate type for each variable in your case `char`

Comment: Thank you! I have changed the int type to char as you said, which is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Node, don't store the data as an int if you want it represented as a char. An int is a numeric type, a char is a character type.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing out ints in your call to data(). if you want this represented as a Character, make sure that data is of type Character.